# Regex only allow x integers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some dates that look like this:

> 20160517124945-0600
>
> 20160322134822.410-0500
>
> 20160322134822-0500

I used [RegexMagic](http://www.regexmagic.com/) to find this regex:

```
(?:[0-9]+){14}\.?(?:[0-9]+){0,3}-(?:[0-9]+){4}
```

The problem is it also accepts things like this:

> 20160322134822-05800

or

> 20160323542352352352134822-0500

Apparently `{}` doesn't mean what I thought it did.  How can I ensure I can only enter 14 digits before the `-` (or optional `.`) and 4 after?

Comment: Go look up what `^` and `$` do in regular expressions.

Comment: `[0-9]+`, the `+` means match 1 to unlimited number of times. Basically you want to take all the `+` out. And probably stop relying on automated tools to find a regex for you.

Comment: this `20160322134822.410-0500` doesn't fit the requirement "14 digits before the - (or optional .) and 4 after"

Comment: the `.###` is optional.

Comment: Not to be too critical, but a few hours studying regex would probably be more productive than the $40 you or your employer presumably spent on the software. This is a super simple regex and someone familiar with the language would probably knock it out in less time than it took you to write your 3 examples

Comment: Conclusion: RegexMagic isn't magic;

Comment: Yeah it's pretty terrible honestly.  I mean, just look at the site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your regex did not function as expected because `(?:[0-9]+){0,3}` means *match 1 or more digits zero, one, two or three times*. That means, it matched any amount of digits.

It seems you need an optional group for the `.` followed with 1+ digits and you need to replace `+` with the limiting quantifiers:

```
^\d{14}(?:\.\d+)?-\d{4}$
```

See the [regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/yL5fP0/1)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string (we need to ensure we only match 14 first digits before `.` or `-`)
- `\d{14}`  - 14 digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of `.` + 1 or more digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `$` -  end of string

```js
var re = /^\d{14}(?:\.\d+)?-\d{4}$/; 
var strs = ['20160517124945-0600', '20160322134822.410-0500', '20160322134822-0500', '20160322134822-05800','20160323542352352352134822-0500'];
for (var s of strs) {
   document.body.innerHTML += s + ": " + re.test(s) + "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: I had to replace all the single backslashes with doubles and now it's working. I also really appreciate all the explanations of each segment!

Comment: You should not use `RegExp("pattern")`, you should use `/pattern/`. I added a JS demo. A constructor notation is only good for defining dynamic patterns or those with many `/` and no special characters. Use literal regex notation (`/.../`) for all static patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^(\d{14})(\.\d{0,3})?-(\d{4})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version:

```
^[0-9]{14}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?-[0-9]{4}$
```

For some reason I always like using [0-9] instead of \d

- So we're doing the start of the string with: ^
- Then 14 numbers 0-9
- Then an optional group starting with a period and then up to three numbers (I'm assuming a period and then no numbers after wouldn't be acceptable.  This is in contrast to what you posted)
- A hyphen
- Four numbers
- Then the end of the string with: $

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could simplify your regexp like this:

```
^(\d{14})(\.\d{3})?(-\d{4})$
```

test https://regex101.com/r/lF9gX0/1